# Xamarin Android en Visual Studio no muestra nada en el apartado grafico

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

estoy empezando a usar Xamarin en visual studio 2022, pero desde que lo descargue estoy teniendo problemas para usarlo, por ejemplo, si compilo y uso el proyecto en mi teléfono salen las cosas, pero aquí en el área de trabajo no aparece nada, es como si fuera invisible o se hubiera ido para atrás ¿alguien sabe que hacer para que sirva?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si estás iniciando, te sugiero que vayas por Net MAUI (la evolución de Xamarin Forms) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/tutorials/notes-app/?view=net-maui-8.0 por cierto, bienvenido a SOes, recuerda realizar el recorrido para que veas la dinámica del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la idea, lamentablemente es algo que me piden de la escuela, no es decisión personal.